# How to insert data once for two input has same name

Tags: php, html, forms

Please have a look 
[Website interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVnOc.png)

I only can insert these data with click both of the submit `<button>`.
I wish to use only one submit `<button>` to submit these data twice.

Here is my code.
As u can see, I `for` loop this `<form>`

```
<?php
 for($x=1; $x<=2; $x++)
   {
?>
<div class="col-lg-6">
<label>Passenger <?php echo $x ?> </label>
 <form role="form" method='post'>
    <div class="form-group">
          <label>Title</label>
          <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="gander" value="Mr" checked>Mr
          </label>
          <label class="radio-inline">
                 <input type="radio" name="gander"  value="Ms">Ms
          </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label>Enter name of Passenger</label>
          <input class="form-control" name='name'>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <label>Enter Passenger Id <?php echo $x ?></label>
     <input class="form-control" placeholder="960529-01-6925" name='ic'>
     </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="addbtn" method="post">Submit Button</button>
    </form>
    </div>

    <?php
   }
  ?>
```

Here is the isset button code

```
    <?php
     if(isset($_POST["addbtn"]))
       {

 $ganderphp = $_POST["gander"];
 $namephp = $_POST["name"];
 $icphp = $_POST["ic"];
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `passenger_data`(`pass_gender`,`pass_name`,`pass_ic`,`Username`)  VALUES ('$ganderphp','$namephp','$icphp','$username')";
 if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
   echo $sql;
 }else {
   echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
 }
   }

?>
```

Its not user friendly because user only can submit data on one of the form first.
I did try to take the submit button out of the looping, but its not working.
I need a solution to make user can submit only once for all these data.

Base on some research, maybe array[] and for each can done this but i just don know how to use it.

Appreciate for any answer.

Comment: You can switch your inputs to submit as arrays, such as `name="gander[]"` then loop over them once the submit button is clicked.

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone after i move submit button out of the loop, i did like this in isset post `for($x=1; $x<=2; $x++)
                               {
                                $ganderphp = $_POST["gander[]"];
                               }` but its not working, the value is missing in sql when its submit to database

Comment: @CheeSengTeo How are getting the `$username` during form processing?

Comment: @RajdeepPaul  $username its a data from session

Comment: @CheeSengTeo I've given an answer below, hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, take the `<form>` and submit `<button>` element outside of the `for` loop, and then change the `name` attributes like this:

```
name="gander[<?php echo $x; ?>]"
name='name[<?php echo $x; ?>]'
```

and

```
name='ic[<?php echo $x; ?>]'
```

So your **HTML** form would be like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <form role="form" method='post'>
<?php
    for($x=1; $x<=2; $x++){
?>
    <label>Passenger <?php echo $x ?> </label>
    <div class="form-group">
          <label>Title</label>
          <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="gander[<?php echo $x; ?>]" value="Mr" checked>Mr
          </label>
          <label class="radio-inline">
                 <input type="radio" name="gander[<?php echo $x; ?>]"  value="Ms">Ms
          </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label>Enter name of Passenger</label>
          <input class="form-control" name='name[<?php echo $x; ?>]'>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <label>Enter Passenger Id <?php echo $x ?></label>
     <input class="form-control" placeholder="960529-01-6925" name='ic[<?php echo $x; ?>]'>
     </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="addbtn" method="post">Submit Button</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

And after submitting, process your form like this:

```
if(isset($_POST["addbtn"])){
    for($x = 1; $x <= 2; ++$x){
        $ganderphp = $_POST["gander"][$x];
        $namephp = $_POST["name"][$x];
        $icphp = $_POST["ic"][$x];

        // construct the query and execute it

    }
}
```

---

**Sidenote:** Learn about [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) because right now your query is susceptible to SQL injection. Also see [how you can prevent SQL injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Its working!  Appreciate your answer so quickly ! Thanks.

Comment: Since, u are note about sql injection, I actually had a big question about this. I am using DB_function to prevent this, but i never success to sql injection anything by `'); DROP TABLE table;--`  so if possible, would u help me to have a look about mine DB_function is working to prevent sql injection?

Comment: In DB_function, i basically write all sql in another page, its really different with stmt. Here is the code in DB_function if i want to add data `public function add($tablename,$colname,$dataname){
 $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$tablename." (".$colname.") VALUES (".$dataname.")";
 $result= mysqli_query(mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","phpstmt"), $sql);
 return $result;
}`

Comment: So in Interface i only need to write like this if i want to add data `dataphp = $_POST["data"];
                                $datatwophp = $_POST["datatwo"];
                                $colname = "data,datatwo";
                                $dataname = "'$dataphp','$datatwophp'";
                                $result = $db->add($tablename,$colname,$dataname);`

Comment: I am sorry, i cant  make the code look better in comment.

Comment: @CheeSengTeo No, that's not correct. Always *prepare*, *bind* and *execute* your queries, because that's how you can prevent SQL injection.

Comment: @CheeSengTeo *Cheers! :-)*